# add list value of a key in a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a following dictionary:

```
centroid = {'A': [1.0, 1.0], 'B': [2.0, 1.0]}
```

Using the above dictionary I am creating two different dictionaries and appending them to a list:

```
for key in centroids:
        clusters_list.append(dict(zip(key, centroids.get(key))))
```

However when I check my cluster_list I get the following data:

```
[{'A': 1.0}, {'B': 2.0}]
```

instead of 
`[{'A': [1.0, 1.0]}, {'B': [2.0, 1.0]}]`.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Why not `clusters_list = [centroid]`?  If you want a copy: `clusters_list = [centroid.copy()]`

Comment: @zondo That'll make a list of one element, not two dictionaries

Comment: @zondo well, i am trying to create two separate dictionaries inside the list.

Comment: @cricket_007: Ah, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

For Python 2:

```
cluster_list = [{k: v} for k, v in centroid.iteritems()]
# [{'A': [1.0, 1.0]}, {'B': [2.0, 1.0]}]
```

For Python 3:

```
cluster_list = [{k: v} for k, v in centroid.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

```
In [1]: from itertools import starmap
In [2]: list(starmap(lambda k,v: {k:v}, centroid.items()))
Out[2]: [{'B': [2.0, 1.0]}, {'A': [1.0, 1.0]}]
```

And of course, it doesn't guarantee the order in the resulting list.